# Get array php bigtee

Tags: php, html

I am a stuck with Bigtree.

For my website I need to know a pageID, you can do that using a function.

```
$nav = $cms->getNavId($path, $previewing = false);
```

But this is what I get back

```
string(2) "15" array(0) { } string(0) ""
```

how can I catch the number (in this case 15)

If I do it this way

```
    $nav = $cms->getNavId($path, $previewing = false);


foreach ($nav as $key) {
echo $key;
}
```

Then I get this output

```
15Array
```

Comment: That return value doesn't make sense. You can only have one value returned from a function.

Comment: `print_r($nav)` provide me that ..

Comment: @dan08 it is returning a traversable (Object/Array) For reference in the docs: https://www.bigtreecms.org/docs/code/core/BigTreeCMS/#getNavId `Return Value: An array containing the page ID and any additional commands.`

Comment: Yea, the `print_r` or `var_dump` would be helpful, because I'm not sure what you have

Comment: can you show getNavId() function's code?

Comment: similar question to this, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102295/why-is-array-in-my-string/

Answer (score 0):

So your loop looks like its doing what you want. If you replaced the `echo` in the loop with a `var_dump` it would be more clear.

So to grab the 15; do this:

```
$nav = $cms->getNavId($path, $previewing = false);

foreach ($nav as $key) {
  if( is_numeric($key) ){
     $navID = $key;
  }
}

var_dump($navID);
```